# Ruby command line parsing

Tags: ruby, parsing, command-line, command-line-arguments

```
class Test

    options = Trollop::options do
        opt :mode, "Select script mode", :default => 0
        opt :net, "Internal IP range", :type => :string
    end

@options = options

    def test
        pp @options
    end
end
```

Why does `@options` return `nil` when I call `test()`?

I've also tried setting `@options` to instance when Trollop is first called. I need to be able to pass the options hash returned from Trollop into different methods in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411944/tass) points out, changing `@options` to `OPTIONS` is one way.

You could also use `@@options;` it's a class variable in either context.

Comment: Thanks a lot the class variable worked, I thought instance variables could be accessed in all methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a class instance variable for option storage then this would work:

```
class Test
   @options = Trollop::options ...

   class << self
     attr_accessor :options
   end

   def test
     pp Test.options
     # or self.class.options
   end
 end

 # And this will work too..
 pp Test.options
```

Otherwise you might want to use a class variable `@@options` or constant, like the other ones pointed out, instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot the class variable worked, I thought instance variables could be accessed in all methods.

Comment: @JamesParker Yes *instance variables* are accessible in all methods, but you created a *class instance variable*. There is a difference. To create an instance variable you normally create it *inside an instance method* `def foo; @instance_var = 123; end`. What you did was create the variable outside of any method, but inside the class = class instance variable. See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a scoping issue. `@options` in class context is an instance variable of the class. In `test`, you access the instance variable `@options` in the current instance. Try constants, aka `OPTIONS`, which have lexical scoping. Maybe someone else knows of a cleaner solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a class instance variable, but when you reference it in the method, you're referencing what looks like an instance variable.

First, you might want to instead use a class variable rather than a class instance variable. There's some information on the distinction [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).

```
class Test

    @@options = Trollop::options do
        opt :mode, "Select script mode", :default => 0
        opt :net, "Internal IP range", :type => :string
    end


    def test
        pp @@options
    end
end

Test.test
```

The other option is to instantiate your class variable when initializing the test object, as below:

```
class Test

    def initialize
        @options = Trollop::options do
            opt :mode, "Select script mode", :default => 0
            opt :net, "Internal IP range", :type => :string
        end
    end


    def test
        pp @options
    end
end

t = Test.new
t.test
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the class variable worked, I thought instance variables could be accessed in all methods.